# C++ question on dependency injection and unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, dependency-injection

Suppose I have a class BigClass that needs a member variable of type SmallClass

```
class BigClass {
.....
private:
SmallClass obj;
};
```

I have 2 problems:

1) I cannot pass a SmallClass object to BigClass's constructor, since BigClass needs to process some files (and get some data) to properly instantiate SmallClass. I know that
the proper way to do dependency injection is to have a constructor `BigClass(SmallClass& obj)`. How do I solve this problem if SmallClass can be instantiated only after BigClass has 
lived for a while?

2) This is how BigClass constructs itself: it loops through files in a directory, reads some of the files to initialize its state. How can I make this unit testable ? What is a proper unit test for constructors that read files from directories to get state?

Answer (score 1):

1) In order to me you have to introduce a factory for SmallClass and having BigClass depending on it for SmallClass instances construction.

2) It seems to me having this in the constructor is a bad idea, maybe having some explicit method would help ( but more is needed to reply correctly ).

Comment: +1 for using a factory.  The factory could be changed for the unit test to create a mock.

Answer (score 0):

Turn

```
SmallClass obj;
```

into

```
SmallClass* obj;
```

Then, make a method

```
setObj(SmallClass* _obj);
```

That way you can instantiate it whenever you want. You can also inject a mocked-out version for testing.

Answer (score 0):

1)  Just make a function in BigClass that you can pass in a SmallClass object whenever you want.  It doesn't have to be in the constructor `func(SmallClass* obj)`

2) I would unit test your BigClass that reads files by having your program make a bunch of files and throw them into a directory.  Then run bigClass over these files and test the individual reads against the known outputs that BigClas is suppose to give, along with any other functionality you would like to test.  Then delete the files when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a two-stage initialisation on `SmallClass`, namely having a constructor that gets it into a stable, but empty state and then have an `init()` function that turns the empty shell of `SmallClass` into a working and usable object.

It's not the most elegant solution (I personally don't like two-stage initalisation as you can have objects floating around that aren't really usable) but it would work in your scenario.

Another option might be to use a `SmallClass *` in `BigClass` and use a factory that creates `SmallClass` object and use that to control the dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a factory, and for the unit test, change the method that creates the object to create a mock instead.

2) You can create another class which has an interface and derived, which is a wrapper around calls to get list of files. Then for the unit test, you pass a mock object. You can either pass object of this class to the constructor of BigClass, or use a factory.

for 1), it is something like this (not tested) :

```
struct Factory
{
  static SmallClassIface* Create()
  {
    return ReallyCreate();
  }

  typedef SmallClassIface* (funcPtr*)();

  static funcPtr creator;

  static SmallClassIface* DefaultCreator()
  {
    return new SmallClass;
  }
};
Factory::funcPtr Factory::creator = &Factory::DefaultCreator();
```

Answer (score 0):

> `BigClass` needs to process some files... to properly instantiate `SmallClass`

I'd advise against having constructors perform I/O. Consider redesigning `BigClass` so the I/O is done outside (before) the call to the `BigClass` constructor, with the results of that I/O passed to the `BigClass` constructor.

> I know that the proper way to do dependency injection

I'd assert (although some would disagree with me) that you **should not** do depenedency injection for objects that are present only as implementation details. In this case, if `BigClass` has no getter method that returns a copy of or reference to the `SmallClass` object, then the presence of `SmallClass` in `BigClass` is an implementation detail that should be irrelevant to your unit tests.

Comment: I understand the need to have constructors not touch the filesystem. But then who does the actual I/O? Another class which does the work and passes the results to BigClass ?